# Have function that returns a list create new columns and expand `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create a `data.table` from a `data.table` that has more numerous rows than the input `data.table`.

```
dt <- data.table(
  A = sample(LETTERS, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(1:1000, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(1:1000, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  D = sample(1:1000, size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

dt.fun <- function(b, c, d) {
  bcd <- b + c + d
  bc <- b + c
  cd <- b + d
  return(list(bcd, bc, cd))
}
```

The results I get back from `dt[, .(dt.fun(B, C, D))), by = c('A')` look like below:

```
   A                                V1
 1: T 1294,1827,1965,1476,1680,2494,...
 2: T  602, 837,1215, 907,1473,1505,...
 3: T 1156,1550,1385,1240,1007,1751,...
 4: B 1666,1894,1696,1683,2276,1530,...
 5: B 1365,1078,1398, 830,1483, 821,...
 6: B  981,1151,1082,1677,1391,1475,...
 7: K 1227,1381,2173,1156,1269,1209,...
 8: K  681,1066,1212, 662, 954, 999,...
 9: K  814, 499,1368,1012, 933, 264,...
10: C  625,2275,1019,1449,1115,2043,...
11: C  149,1532, 927,1230, 712,1652,...
12: C  617,1627, 103, 850, 988,1067,...
13: J 1122,2048,2347,2013,1974,1146,...
14: J  298,1158,1525,1119,1362,1106,...
15: J  908,1350,1692,1055,1181, 654,...
16: E 1918,1661,1684,1378,2442,1262,...
17: E 1198, 817, 899,1340,1578, 741,...
18: E 1025,1392, 949, 808,1826, 583,...
19: M 1818,1915,1716,1083,1524,1402,...
20: M 1305, 973, 871, 993, 966, 574,...
21: M 1475,1196, 926, 918,1042,1089,...
22: U 1718,1962,1880, 564, 726,1249,...
23: U 1371,1162,1365, 430, 147, 909,...
24: U 1250,1183,1019, 246, 722, 651,...
25: G 2405,2419, 632,1753,1993,1803,...
26: G 1797,1498, 307,1325,1422,1184,...
27: G 1582,1682, 488,1335,1015,1518,...
28: P 1889,1839,1445,1603,1034,1161,...
29: P 1130,1271, 789,1556, 906, 432,...
30: P 1671,1304, 846, 818, 819,1061,...
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the function to return each element of the list as a separate column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what your expected output is, but I'll take a few guesses.

First, reproducible data, I'll use a random seed:

```r
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(
  A = sample(LETTERS, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(1:1000, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(1:1000, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
  D = sample(1:1000, size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
)
head(dt,3)
#         A     B     C     D
#    <char> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:      Q   344   108   385
# 2:      E   765   477   526
# 3:      A   203   667   425
```

From here, your `dt.fun` function is returning a `list`, so we don't need to encapsulate its call in `.( ... )`, we can use it straight-up.

```r
dt[, dt.fun(B, C, D), by = .(A) ]
#            A    V1    V2    V3
#       <char> <int> <int> <int>
#    1:      Q   837   452   729
#    2:      Q  1541   770  1529
#    3:      Q  1242   656   693
#    4:      Q   451   338   127
#    5:      Q  2006  1071  1105
#    6:      Q  1831  1147   869
#    7:      Q  1325   996  1237
#    8:      Q  1860  1385   937
#    9:      Q  1334  1023   748
#   10:      Q  1403   983   539
#   ---                         
#  991:      S  1587  1189   587
#  992:      S  2039  1063  1431
#  993:      S  1485   532  1449
#  994:      S  1976   985  1010
#  995:      S  2143  1444  1404
#  996:      S  1824  1394  1132
#  997:      S  1619  1126  1141
#  998:      S   863   721   236
#  999:      S  1496   763  1187
# 1000:      S   770   193   741
```

Since your function does not name the columns and we did not assign them, they were assigned `"V1"`, etc. We can assign them by either changing your function to end with

```r
  return(list(X=bcd, Y=bc, Z=cd))
```

or provide them in the assignment:

```r
head(dt[, setNames(dt.fun(B, C, D), c("X", "Y", "Z")), by = .(A) ], 3)
#         A     X     Y     Z
#    <char> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:      Q   837   452   729
# 2:      Q  1541   770  1529
# 3:      Q  1242   656   693
```

If you are hoping to *append* the columns, though, and preserve the original `"B"` and such, then we can do:

```r
head(dt[, c("X", "Y", "Z") := dt.fun(B, C, D), by = .(A) ], 3)
#         A     B     C     D     X     Y     Z
#    <char> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:      Q   344   108   385   837   452   729
# 2:      E   765   477   526  1768  1242  1291
# 3:      A   203   667   425  1295   870   628
```

or borrowing from Waldi's since-deleted answer, we can `c(.SD, ...)` to append it. I'll combine that with my `setNames(.)` recommendation, not needed if you change the names in your `dt.fun` function.

```r
head(dt[, c(.SD, setNames(dt.fun(B, C, D), c("X", "Y", "Z"))), by = .(A) ], 3)
#         A     B     C     D     X     Y     Z
#    <char> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:      Q   344   108   385   837   452   729
# 2:      Q   758    12   771  1541   770  1529
# 3:      Q   107   549   586  1242   656   693
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a vector of new column names and assign the output to it.

```
library(data.table)

dt.fun <- function(b, c, d) {
  bcd <- b + c + d
  bc <- b + c
  cd <- b + d
  return(list(bcd, bc, cd))
}

new_cols = c('bcd', 'bc', 'cd')

dt[, (new_cols) := dt.fun(B, C, D), A]
dt

#      A   B   C   D  bcd   bc   cd
#   1: F 789  12 941 1742  801 1730
#   2: O 701  51 275 1027  752  976
#   3: T 996 179 973 2148 1175 1969
#   4: T 407 392  88  887  799  495
#   5: Z 476 311 489 1276  787  965
#  ---                             
# 996: D 266 841 120 1227 1107  386
# 997: Q 229 218 908 1355  447 1137
# 998: E 196 326 604 1126  522  800
# 999: W 882 106 488 1476  988 1370
#1000: J 580 180 679 1439  760 1259
```